# Existing ODBC Machine Sources Disappears?

Tags: ms-access, odbc

So this is just more of a question I want a general insight to, as supposed to troubleshooting something. The drivers can be re-added, so there is no problem there.

My question is this. Our company has this one large database file that a couple of people use, where there are some linked tables from a MySQL backend. Until today, no matter the user the ODBC connection to these tables were working fine, where it was running on a Machine data source instance named "django_db" on the old driver version of "ODBC ANSI Driver 5.3".

But suddenly today the connection stopped for a couple of users, where later I found out the reason was that the pre-defined data source instance named "django_db" was removed from the Machine Data Source list for some reason. Like I mentioned before, it was a quick fix of re-defining that instance back in, but I was wondering in case of Microsoft Access (where this problem occurred), why would that ODBC connector disappear in the first place? Could a recent update in MS Access cause this?

Comment: Sounds like a logical conclusion to me. The fix has held?

Comment: @June7 I have to see. It works fine for now, but if the Microsoft updates are continuously going to be causing this.... well.... owo

Comment: Updates to Access don't go crawling the registry to delete entries. So, don't know what occurred, but I can't see how this was due to Access. Maybe such users are logging in as different users, and thus they don't have rights to the registry entires, or they are gone because of a different user. This is some system/setup/user issue, but certainly not a access issue.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal No they wouldn't be, since the shared db file forces its users to login under the same "admin" credentials. And just recently another user has experienced this problem. So based what you are saying I'm assuming that one day all of their registry rights have been removed somehow. What would cause that then?

Comment: Well, perhaps they log on under a different name? So they get a different registry for machine local user? Perhaps some are part of a domain logon, and some logons are not? I really don't know, but I am hard pressed to accept that Access is running around and deleting, or modifying registry entries without Access code to do so. So, perhaps the machines you find with this issue is the result of the user logon on under (with) a different logon then what they used previous.